# phpMyAdmin configuration storage simple setup?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am missing phpMyAdmin configuration storage for all database instances/ websites on my dedicated server, so when I for instance wish to change any phpMyAdmin settings permanently I get this message:

> Your preferences will be saved for current session only. Storing them
>   permanently requires phpMyAdmin configuration storage.

Is there a simple way of activating phpMyAdmin configuration storage at one place for all databases, eg. some WHM setup or similar, as from what I can find on this forum and other place are either obsolete info or won't work for me at all ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> 'phpmyadmin configuration storage' comes from the 'phpmyadmin' database that you must import to the server

After this, you will be able to permanently keep changes to the settings of phpmyadmin.

1. go to `localhost/phpmyadmin`
2. click `import` > `choose file`
3. find `create_tables.sql` > (wamp64\apps\phpmyadmin5.1.1\sql\create_tables.sql)
4. click go then re-login phpmyadmin

reference:
[documentation](http://underpop.online.fr/p/phpmyadmin/help/phpmyadmin-configuration-storage.htm)
| [tutorial](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-enable-phpmyadmin-configuration-storage-to-gain-more-options-and-security/)